# How to add negabinary numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, binary, binary-operations

A `negabinary` is a number with a base as -2. I want to add two such numbers. I know how to convert them into the corresponding decimal numbers but wanted to add them right away without conversion to decimal system.

For eg, if two numbers are `1011` and `1110`, the output is `110001` in the `negabinary` addition. I understand the concept of a signed bit but could not comprehend this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You add them just like regular binary numbers, except the carry is negative and should be subtracted from each column instead of added to it.
$$
\begin{align}
1\color{red}1\phantom{1}\color{red}1\phantom{11}&\\
1011&\\
{}+1110&\\
\hline
=110001&
\end{align}
$$
(I'm using the color red to signify a carry with a negative value.) For that last $\color{red}1$, note that translates to $1$ with a *positive* (black) carry of $1$ (as $-1$ in regular numbers is $11$ in negabinary).

For a more convoluted example, consider
$$
\begin{align}
1\color{red}11\color{red}1\phantom{0000}&\\
101010&\\
{}+101100&\\
\hline
=11110110\end{align}
$$
The two lone negative $1$'s each give a result of $1$ in their respective columns, and a *positive* (black) carry of $1$. The column where you now have three (black) $1$'s gives (as "normal") a result of $1$ and a negative (red) carry to the next column. And this ought to address anything that can possibly happen in a column when adding two numbers together.

In the case that we have four $1$'s in one column, we have 0 for that column and 1 for the two consecutive columns (as 4 in decimal is equivalent to 100 in negabinary). Here is an example:
$$
\begin{align}
&\\
00101 (+5)&\\
{}+00111 (+3)&\\
\hline
=11000 (+8)\end{align}
$$

Comment: These seem to be different negabinary to these: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=negabinary+6

Comment: No, it's exactly the same. The numbers you have here are $-9$ and $-6$, and they add to $-15$. All is well. (WolframAlpha is a bit wonky; if I ask it to convert $-6$ to negabinary, it will give me the exact same result as for $6$. That doesn't seem right.)

Comment: @Arthur, so this means `101010` + `101100` would equal to `11110110`?

Comment: I wasn't worried whether all is well with your answer - more about whether all is well with Wolfram Alpha and its alternative representations which continue infinitely to the right.

Comment: @user334732 I get the same result as you do for $101010+101100$. Carries behave a bit weirdly, but one can get used to it.  As for the representation of $6$, I get that to be $11010$ (just guessing: $16-8 -2$, but also attainable by adding $101+1$). So I have no idea what WA is doing.

Comment: @Arthur, can you help me in adding 101010, 101100?
I am bit confused when I have to deduct 1(the carry) from 0, as it happens to be in this case.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava As I said, carries behave rather strangely. Remember that $-1$ becomes $11$, so if you're carrying a negative $1$ into an empty column, then the result is a $1$ and a carry of _positive_ $1$. And if this results in you getting three $1$'s in a column, then that's a result of $1$ with a ("regular") negative $1$ carry.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava I added that as an example.

Comment: When you end up carrying a negative $1$ into an empty column you can either write $11$ immediately or you can write $1$ and carry a positive $1$ which then goes immediately in the result. The final result is the same either way. I see that at the moment you have shown one technique in one example and the other in the other example.

Comment: @DavidK You're right. I fixed it so that it's more consistent, using the more careful strategy in both cases.

Comment: In case anyone wants to code this solution or needs to understand the dry run, click [here](https://pastebin.com/y5rNSFJe)!

Answer (score 2):

There's a good rule for negabinary addition, which is really easy to use, and comprises a set of three cases which account for all eventualities, and is "sign-transitive" in the sense that you can apply it in any position, be it a negative or positive place-value:

$1+1=110$

$1+1+1=111$

$1+11=0$

(I'm assuming $1+0=1$ is obvious)

I was trying to remember where I saw this but it's 8 minutes into [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8kXpOMQVj8) which contains some other valuable insights.

Comment: @Arthur ^^ also useful.

Comment: Thank you so much @user3344732